# Facebook Registration and Login Slim Framework PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have an api, which has a regular email password login. But I want to add facebook logins.

1. Do I need an app registered on facebook?
2. Do I need to force users to register using facebook, or just link their facebook account to their account and use it as a form of auth.
3. How does this tie into mobile apps? Given I am writing the API, what info does the client provide for a facebook login and what do I need to store?

There is a plethora of info out there and I am not sure where to start. I am writing an API, but I am not sure how much work my API has to do and how much the client just has to deal directly with facebook. Any specific guides tailored more toward what I am doing would be great.

Answer (score 4):

A simple library called [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) available that takes the pain out of building a social login feature.

Here is a very detailed [tutorial from Sitepoint.](http://www.sitepoint.com/social-logins-php-hybridauth/)

*I am answering this even though this question in 1 year old, because this is visible on google search top 3 links. It might help someone who stumble upon this like I did few months ago.*

Comment: Will this work if I already implemented my own authentication system(ie already have a mechanism to register users all they have to do is enter their name, email and password)?  I just want to retrieve the name, hashed password and email and put in my already builtin users table, is this possible or am I over simplifying this?

Comment: They do have a class which can be extended by your own login system easily. In one project, I just had to encapsulate the functions into a class, and change how it is called. In another I had factory class which created objects for FB and my own login system. They have few more releases since then, and updated a lot of things, best take a good reading of [their documentations](https://hybridauth.github.io/documentation.html)